# Conditional formating between two tables

Tags: excel

Is there a way to compare each value of one table to another without using rules for every cell?

Table1 contains in each cell a number that a person choose, each person chooses 10 numbers.

Table2 starts empty and 5 numbers are inserted every week.

The result is to color the cells in Table1 that's value is equal to any of the cells in Table2
I've tried using an Equal To format but it only works it doesn't let compare one table to anothe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `MATCH()` function to CF rule.

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(B5,$F$5:$F$9,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Before using your solution I tried to replicate your example and It didn't work, when I paste the formula it gives an error that there is something with the formula.

Comment: Based on regional settings you may need to use semicolon `;` instead of comma `.`. Try `=ISNUMBER(MATCH(B5;$F$5:$F$9;0))`